# Fix location of stippling for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have been trying to stipple contour plots to show locations where values are statistically significant. However, when I do this in subplots where the significance is the same, the stippling looks different based on the random location of the filled stipples. I have reproduced the problem below. Is there a way to fix the location of the stipples so that they look the same when plotted? Or is there a better way to stipple plots?

These 2 subplots are plotting the exact same data, but the stipples look different.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Create some random data
x = np.arange(0,100,1)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
stipp = 10*np.random.rand(len(x),len(x))

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

#Plot stippling 
ax1.contourf(x,y,stipp,[0,4],colors='none',hatches='.')
ax2.contourf(x,y,stipp,[0,4],colors='none',hatches='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hatching is applied on a canvas level. Depending on where your axes starts within the canvas, hatches are at a different position. I'm very uncertain about what you are trying to achieve, but I would guess that hatching is not a solution for it.

Comment: I have 3 sets of simulations and am comparing all three in 3 subplots. I want to use the hatching to highlight the areas of the data where the simulations are statistically different. This stippling is helpful since it does not clutter the image, but I want them to look the same since the boundaries are important.

Comment: You could use a `scatter` plot, where points are at positions that are relevant.

Comment: That should work, I always forget about the good 'ole scatter plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone wants to know, the best way to stipple multiple subplots with similar statistical significance is to use a scatter plot as recommended above instead of contouring. Just make sure to sample the data sparingly so you don't have a high density of dots next to each other.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib  import pyplot as plt

#Create some random data
x = np.arange(0,100,1)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
stipp = 10*np.random.rand(len(x),len(x))

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

#Plot stippling 
ax1.scatter(x[(stipp<=4) & (stipp>=0)][::5],y[(stipp<=4) & (stipp>=0)][::5])
ax2.scatter(x[(stipp<=4) & (stipp>=0)][::5],y[(stipp<=4) & (stipp>=0)][::5])

plt.show()
```

[image]